# Use spannable to highlight only part of already added text

Tags: android, spannable

I add a text like this:

```
tv.setText("This is text created with StringBuilder");
```

Then I track which word a user longclicks on, and want to highlight that word for some short period of time:

```
tv.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        int offset = tv.getOffsetForPosition(coordinates.get(0), coordinates.get(1));
        int[] offsets = getWordOffsets(text.toString(), offset);
        int startOffset = offsets[0];
        int endOffset = offsets[1];

        // here I want to highlight the word starting from startOffset to endOffset
```

I've read that I should use `SpannableString`, however most examples show that I should created new `SpannableString` using the entire text, and then I can add styles to part of it. Is there any way to make part of the text in `TextView` spannable? Or should I create new `SpannableString` strings from `TextView` content and set spans every time the long click event is triggered?

Comment: `Or should I create new SpannableString strings from TextView content and set spans every time the long click event is triggered`, yes you have to

Comment: I see, thanks, how's this solution in terms of perfomance? I have about 1000 words in my TextView. Maybe there's a better alternative to this approach?

Answer (score 1):

you can use some countdown timer

```
 //___ HIGHLIGHT HERE ______
    new CountDownTimer(500,500){

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            //___ UN HIGHLIGHT HERE ______

        }
    }.start();
```

and for the highlight you can use something like

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FF0000'>text</font>"));
```

Comment: thanks, I actually don't need to hide it within 5 seconds, I need to hide it when dialog closes, I made this task up for example, the question is about highlighting part of the string. I'll upvote for the new method `CountDownTimer` I didn't know :) And how to use `Html.fromHtml` with the other string? As you outlined it'll highlight entire text, not one word

Comment: mmm... you can   <font color='#FF0000'>highlighted text</font>unhihlightedtext<font color='#00FF00'>green highlighted</font> and so on. It's just like html and css on the web

Comment: yeah, but that's still is almost equivalent to creating spannable strings as I'd have to replace TextView content every time the word is longclicked.